Retrieve complicated data from MS SQL Database
I have table [Analogues] with columns and data below:



ID-Items
ID-Items analogs




2
10


3
11


2
11


11
7


8
2


7
4


6
9



I would like to retrieve recursively all analogues of item with [ID-Items]=11.
SQL code:
declare @ID as bigint = 11
;            
WITH SourceCTE AS
( 
SELECT 
        ib.[ID-Items]
      , ib.[ID-Items analogs] 
  FROM          [an] ib
  WHERE         ib.[ID-Items]=@ID or ib.[ID-Items analogs] =@ID
 
UNION ALL

SELECT 
       ib2.[ID-Items]
      ,ib2.[ID-Items analogs] 
  FROM          [an] ib2
  INNER JOIN    SourceCTE s             
  ON ib2.[ID-Items analogs] = s.[ID-Items]


) 

SELECT          * 
FROM            SourceCTE
GROUP BY [ID-Items],[ID-Items analogs] 
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 100)

but this SQL doesn't retrieve item with ID=10 which is also analogous of this item.
My desired outcome as text:



ID-Items
ID-Items analogs




2
10


2
11


3
11


8
2


11
7


7
4



Any help?

I don't get it. item 11 has an analog of 7 so can't recurse any deeper than that. Please add your desired outcome as text.

What is an "analog"? Do you mean all children? All Parents? Both?

11 also is analogue of 2 and 3. There is also a reverse relations.
"Analogues" are drug identifiers.

You should add the expected results

Why is 7,4 missing from desired outcome  when 8,2 is included? come to think of it the entire sample includes all analogs of 11 , it would be helpful if the sample was representative.

@P.Salmon because OP doesn't know what he wants probably

P.Salmon you are right.  I have edited the text of my question.

The problem is that 11 is analogous of 2 and 2 is analogous of 10. Hence 10 is analogous of 11.
And I want to retrive this data too.

The process is define the anchor, get all the analogs then iterate. If you don't have to use a recursive query then this model might do if you wrap it in a loop in a stored procedure. https://dbfiddle.uk/AESAAXlF
create table t
(id int identity ,item int, item_analog int)
go
insert into t values
(2  ,10),
(3  ,11),
(2  ,11),
(11 ,7),
(8  ,2),
(7  ,4),
(6  ,9);

go

create table t1(iteration int, item int, previtem int)
go

truncate table t1
declare @anchor int
set @anchor = 11
insert into t1 values (1,@anchor,0)
declare @iteration int
set @iteration = 2
insert into t1
select @iteration,
        case when t.item = t1.item then t.item_analog else t.item end,
       t1.item
from t1
join t on (t1.item = t.item) or (t1.item = t.item_analog) 
where t1.iteration = @iteration - 1

--select * from t1

delete from t1 where iteration = 3
set @iteration = 3
insert into t1
select * from
(
select @iteration iteration,
        case when t.item = t1.item then t.item_analog else t.item end item,
        case when t.item = t1.item then t.item else t.item_analog end pitem
from t1
join t on (t1.item = t.item) or (t1.item = t.item_analog) 
where t1.iteration = @iteration - 1
) s 
where not exists(select 1 from t1 where t1.item = s.item)

--all analogs
select * from t1

--result as in question
select t.item,t.item_analog
from t1 
join t on (t1.item = t.item and t1.previtem = t.item_analog) or
          (t1.previtem = t.item and t1.item = t.item_analog)
order by id

--use this to terminate loop
select max(iteration) from t1

and here's an SP
create  procedure p
(@anchor int)
as
begin
declare @iteration int
truncate table t1
insert into t1 values (1,@anchor,0)
set @iteration = 2
while @iteration < 10
begin
insert into t1
select * from
(
select @iteration iteration,
        case when t.item = t1.item then t.item_analog else t.item end item,
        case when t.item = t1.item then t.item else t.item_analog end pitem
from t1
join t on (t1.item = t.item) or (t1.item = t.item_analog) 
where t1.iteration = @iteration - 1
) s 
where not exists(select 1 from t1 where t1.item = s.item)
if (select max(iteration) from t1) <> @iteration
begin
    print concat('quitting:',@iteration)
    break
end
set @iteration = @iteration + 1
end
end

